# how i can slove this error,SQLSTATE[42000]?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-update, sql-insert

please help me to solve this error.i tired from searching solution...
error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE name=NULL' at line 1

my database have 3 column=id(int),name(varchar),comment(varchar) and i want insert comment to it.

my php code :

```
<?php
include "./Config.php";
include './MyPDO.php';

  $response = array() ;
  $connect = MyPDO::getInstance();

  $name = $_REQUEST['name'];
  $comment=$_REQUEST['comment'];

        $query =  " INSERT INTO user "
                . " (comment) "
                . " VALUES "
                . " (:comment) "
                . " WHERE name=:name ";

        $stmt = $connect->prepare($query);
        $stmt->bindParam(":name",$name);
        $stmt->bindParam(":comment",$comment);
        try {
                $stmt->execute();
                $response['massage'] = "sucess";
                echo json_encode($response);
                exit;
        } catch (PDOException $ex) { 
                $response['massage'] = "error";
                $response['error']=$ex->getMessage();
                echo json_encode($response);
        }
```

Comment: `INSERT` is for creating new rows, `UPDATE` is for creating new rows. It makes no sense to have `WHERE` in an `INSERT` query.

Comment: thank you, i'm just learn php one week..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you mixed the syntax here. You seem to want to update an existing record. Use

```
update user
set comment = :comment
where name = :name
```

`insert` if for creating a new record.

Answer (score 0):

The `insert into ... values()` syntax does not take a `where` clause.

If you want to `insert`, then:

```
insert into user(name, comment) values(:name, :comment)
```

But actually it looks like you might want an `update`:

```
update users set comment = :comment where name = :name;
```

The former creates a new record in the table, with the given name and comment.

The latter modifies the already-existing record that has the same `name` and sets its `comment` value.